# MongoDB: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb

Installed Mongodb a few weeks ago and worked fine with it until today
This happens when I want to start:

```
PS C:\mongodb> mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-05-16T15:30:35.754+0200 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, 
connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: 
A connection could not be established because the target computer refused to connect. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-05-16T15:30:35.761+0200 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-05-16T15:30:35.761+0200 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
PS C:\mongodb>
```

What can I do to make the connection possible again?
Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Considering this 'suddenly' happened, can you verify the mongod is still running? when you run 'mongo' it attempts to connect the mongod with the default settings 127.0.0.1 & 27017 - so check this is active first

Comment: After I run the command "net start mongodb":  The MongoDB service was started successfully.

Comment: I only executed the "net start mongodb" command when installing the DB, otherwise "mongo" was enough to open the Mongo DB shell. There was also a connection to the databases within nodejs. How do I have to start and end the server connection correctly?

Comment: Check the task manager and confirm that there is a `mongod` process running.